# What is the "instance" being passed to the to_representation function of my ListSerializer?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

The goal of this project is to create an API that refreshes hourly with the most up to date betting odds for a list of games that I'll be scraping hourly from the internet. The goal structure for the JSON returned will be each game as the parent object and the nested children will be the top 1 record for each of linesmakers being scraped by updated date. My understanding is that the best way to accomplish this is to modify the to_representation function within the ListSerializer to return the appropriate queryset.

Because I need the game_id of the parent element to grab the children of the appropriate game, I've attempted to pull the game_id out of the data that gets passed. The issue is that this line looks to be populated correctly when I see what it contains through an exception, but when I let the full code run, I get a list index is out of range exception.

For ex.

```
class OddsMakerListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, data):
        game = data.all()[0].game_id

        #if I put this here it evaluates to 1 which should run the raw sql below correctly
        raise Exception(game) 
        data = OddsMaker.objects.filter(odds_id__in = RawSQL(''' SELECT o.odds_id
                                                                    FROM gamesbackend_oddsmaker o
                                                              INNER JOIN (
                                                                          SELECT game_id
                                                                               , oddsmaker
                                                                               , max(updated_datetime)            as last_updated
                                                                            FROM gamesbackend_oddsmaker
                                                                           WHERE game_id = %s
                                                                        GROUP BY game_id
                                                                               , oddsmaker
                                                                         ) l on o.game_id = l.game_id
                                                                            and o.oddsmaker = l.oddsmaker
                                                                            and o.updated_datetime = l.last_updated
                                                              ''', [game]))
        #if I put this here the data appears to be populated correctly and contain the right data
        raise Exception(data)
        data = [game for game in data]
        return data
```

Now, if I remove these raise Exceptions, I get the list index is out of range. My initial thought was that there's something else that depends on "data" being returned as a list, so I created the list comprehension snippet, but that doesn't resolve the issue.

So, my question is 1) Is there an easier way to accomplish what I'm going for? I'm not using a postgres backend so distinct on isn't available to me. and 2) If not, its not clear to me what instance is that's being passed in or what is expected to be returned. I've consulted the documentation and it looks as though it expects a dictionary and that might be part of the issue, but again the error message references a list. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior

I appreciate any help in understanding what is going on here in advance.

Edit:
The rest of the serializers:

```
class OddsMakerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        list_serializer_class = OddsMakerListSerializer
        model = OddsMaker
        fields = ('odds_id','game_id','oddsmaker','home_ml',
                  'away_ml','home_spread','home_spread_odds',
                  'away_spread_odds','total','total_over_odds',
                  'total_under_odds','updated_datetime')


class GameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    oddsmaker_set = OddsMakerSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = ('game_id','date','sport', 'home_team',
                  'away_team','home_score', 'away_score',
                  'home_win','away_win', 'game_completed',
                  'oddsmaker_set')
```

models.py:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    game_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    sport=models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)
    home_team = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)
    away_team = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)
    home_score = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    away_score = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    home_win = models.BooleanField(default=0, null=True)
    away_win = models.BooleanField(default=0, null=True)
    game_completed = models.BooleanField(default=0, null=True)

class OddsMaker(models.Model):
    odds_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    game = models.ForeignKey('Game', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    oddsmaker = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    home_ml = models.IntegerField(default=999999)
    away_ml = models.IntegerField(default=999999)
    home_spread = models.FloatField(default=999)
    home_spread_odds = models.IntegerField(default=9999)
    away_spread_odds = models.IntegerField(default=9999)
    total = models.FloatField(default=999)
    total_over_odds = models.IntegerField(default=999)
    total_under_odds = models.IntegerField(default=999)
    updated_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

views.py:

```
class GameView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):      
  queryset = Game.objects.all()             
  serializer_class = GameSerializer
```

Thanks

Comment: Show us the `models.py` and the view using your serializer.

Comment: @GrandPhuba done. I edited the post to contain the info. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, I added an answer. I'll update it according to the additional information

Comment: I updated my answer. Let me know how it goes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### To answer the question in the title:

The `instance` being passed to the `Serializer.to_representation()` is the instance you pass when initializing the serializer

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
Serializer(queryset, many=True)

instance = MyModel.objects.all().first()
Serializer(data)
```

Usually you don't have to inherit from `ListSerializer` per se. You can inherit from `BaseSerializer` and whenever you pass `many=True` during initialization, it will automatically 'become`a`ListSerializer`. [You can see this in action here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L117)

### To answer your problem

```
from django.db.models import Max
class OddsMakerListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, data): # data passed is a queryset of oddsmaker                 
        # Do your filtering here
        latest_date = data.aggregate(
            latest_date=Max('updated_datetime')
        ).get('latest_date').date()   
        latest_records = data.filter(
            updated_date_time__year=latest_date.year,
            updated_date_time__month=latest_date.month,
            updated_date_time__day=latest_date.day
        )
        return super().to_representation(latest_records)
```

Comment: I'm sorry if this is obvious, but what is meant when you say "Usually you don't have to inherit from ListSerializer per se."?

I just changed the code to inherit BaseSerializer to see if and how it worked, and it broke mentioning "__init__() got unexpected keyword child."

With regard to the code it worked perfectly once I added () to the end of the date call if you want to add that to your snippit.